# Git create repos on the fly?

Tags: git, gitosis

Is it possible to allow for a user to push new GIt repos without having to manually add them to the gitosis.conf every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://zcentric.com/2010/08/25/gitosis-with-wildcard-support/) blog post, gitosis does not support wildcard repositories. The author does however link to a patched version of gitosis ([here](https://github.com/mzupan/gitosis)) that supposedly provides this functionality. I have not used it.

I'm not sure if this will be of any help to you, but it's worth noting that the "successor" to gitosis, [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), has built-in support for wildcard repositories (documentation [here](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/wildcard-repositories.mkd)).